# Default Output of a Type as Instance.ToString() in Powershell

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-module

I have a Powershell Cmdlet,  it returns an object which PowerShell writes to the host nicely in a table for me.

```
$> Get-SolarLunarName -Year 1700 -Month 12

SolarDateTime       Year LunarMonth LunarDay
26/12/1700 00:00:00 1700         12       16
```

However, I like the default behaviour for DateTime.

```
$> Get-Date

Tuesday, 26 November 2019 21:15:45
```

I really want PowerShell to write my type to the host as a string. e.g. "1700/12/16"

I understand these formats can be overridden with xml files, for example bundled with a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) is a little light on examples.  I came up with this having trawled through a lot of unrelated examples on the web.  The errors produced as I attempted to import the Module complete with an Format file were actually the most helpful in producing a valid file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
<ViewDefinitions>
<View>
  <Name>ToString</Name>
  <ViewSelectedBy>
    <TypeName>My.FullyQualified.Type</TypeName>
  </ViewSelectedBy>
  <CustomControl>
    <CustomEntries>
    <CustomEntry>
      <CustomItem>
      <ExpressionBinding>
             <ScriptBlock>
              $_.tostring()
            </ScriptBlock>
      </ExpressionBinding>  
      </CustomItem>  
    </CustomEntry>
    </CustomEntries>
  </CustomControl>
</View>
</ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

You can put more or less what you want inside a `<CustomItem>`, in this case  `<ExpressionBinding>` handles the object in the pipeline with $_ in normal PowerShell syntax. You can have arbitrary text and spacing with other tags.

I saved this file as "MyModule.Format.ps1xml" and included in the module manifest and module package:

```
# Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
FormatsToProcess = @("MyModule.Format.ps1xml")
```

There is an example of a more complex `<ExpressionBinding>` [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PingMe/1.0/Content/PingMe.Format.ps1xml).